# How change text (foreground) and background color in image using QImage in Qt?

Tags: qt, qimage

I can change the background of QImage by doing this:

```
QPainter painter(&image);
painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Darken);
painter.fillRect(image.rect(), QColor("#0000FF"));
```

I can also change the foreground of QImage by doing this:

```
QPainter painter(&image);
painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Lighten);
painter.fillRect(image.rect(), QColor("#FF0000"));
```

But how change both of them at once?

Note: If we run both of this codes, the result will be wrong.

Comment: you can use setStyleSheet of your object for example :  nameEdit->setStyleSheet("color: blue; background-color: yellow");

Comment: @EhsanPanahi, It's not text widget, It's image and I want change colors of scanned document :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
void ClassName:recolor(QImage *image, const QColor &foreground, const QColor &background)
{
    if (image->format() != QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied) {
        // qCWarning(OkularUiDebug) << "Wrong image format! Converting...";
        *image = image->convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    }

    Q_ASSERT(image->format() == QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);

    const float scaleRed = background.redF() - foreground.redF();
    const float scaleGreen = background.greenF() - foreground.greenF();
    const float scaleBlue = background.blueF() - foreground.blueF();

    for (int y=0; y<image->height(); y++) {
        QRgb *pixels = reinterpret_cast<QRgb*>(image->scanLine(y));

        for (int x=0; x<image->width(); x++) {
            const int lightness = qGray(pixels[x]);
            pixels[x] = qRgba(scaleRed * lightness + foreground.red(),
                           scaleGreen * lightness + foreground.green(),
                           scaleBlue * lightness + foreground.blue(),
                           qAlpha(pixels[x]));
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
QColor foreground = QColor("#FF0000");
QColor background = QColor("#0000FF");
recolor(&image, foreground, background);
```

I got this code from the source code of "Okular" program.